# Is Civi having a separate copy of jQuery inefficient?

Tags: javascript

In my html page source I can see 2 copies of jQuery; one for Drupal, and the other for CiviCRM. Surely this isn't very efficient. Is there a way to reconcile the two?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wrote a Drupal module to do just that!

https://www.drupal.org/project/civi_jquery

It allows Drupal and CiviCRM to share the same copy of jQuery, and resolves redundant plugins so the browser has a lot less javascript to download and run.

Maybe someone could do something similar for Wordpress?

Comment: Sounds like a great idea.   We should be registering and loading the copy that ships with WP.   However, we will need to deal with situations where wp is not bootstrapped.   Sounds like a great sprint task.